# Logarithmic mapping and Exponential mapping on python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm learning image treatment using the python libraries PIL and OpenCV2 and I want to apply Logarithmic mapping and Exponential mapping on a black and white image.

I've written this code to apply the logarithmic mapping:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
photo = cv2.imread('TurtleLuminance.jpg')
c = 255/math.log(1+255)
photoLogarithmic = c * cv2.log(1 + photo)
cv2.imshow('Logarithmic', photoLogarithmic)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The formula is [Logarithmic mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovN2X.png) but I have an error on line 7 `photoLogarithmic = c * cv2.log(1 + photo)`.

And for the Exponential mapping I don't know how to aply the formula
[Exponential mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQDxE.png).

If someone can explain to me how to do this I'll be very greatful.

The error is:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 5 || depth == 6) in log, file /io/opencv/modules/core/src/mathfuncs.cpp, line 701
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/rem/Desktop/Py/ImagesTre/tests/Logarithmic/Logarithmic.py", line 7, in <module>
photoLogarithmic = c * cv2.log(1 + photo)
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/core/src/mathfuncs.cpp:701: error: (-215) depth == 5 || depth == 6 in function log
```

---

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
photo = cv2.imread('TurtleLuminance.jpg')
photo = photo.astype(float)
c = 255/math.log(1+250)
photoLogarithmic = c * (cv2.log(1 + photo))
cv2.imshow('Logarithmic', photoLogarithmic)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The result is

[image]

Any idea why did a get this?

Comment: Can you put the error message in the question? From a cursory impression, `cv2.log(1 + photo)` is extremely problematic if the data type is `uint8` and you have array values in `photo` at `255`; this overflows to `0`, and `log(0)` is undefined.

Comment: Sure I'll put the error

Comment: it says that it was expecting depth to be 5 or 6. That would be CV_32F or CV_64F, or in other words, float or double. Try converting your image to floats before doing the operations. Also, I am not sure if is intended, since the name of the file looks like you are expecting a one channel image, but this one will have 3 by default (look at the imread documentation)

Comment: I tried to convert the image to floats and it works but I don't have the result that I expected.
I'll put my new code in the question with the image that i got.